# What is the name of this squiggle symbol?

Tags: terminology, typography, symbols

I came across a strange symbol while reading [the report on the ALGOL 58 programming language](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/ALGOL/report/Algol58_preliminary_report_CACM.pdf/) (p. 19):

[image: Form: Δ ~ procedure I(Pᵢ) =: I(Pₒ), I(Pᵢ) =: I(Pₒ), SQUIGGLE SQUIGGLE SQUIGGLE, I(Pᵢ) =: I(Pₒ) Δ ; Δ ; SQUIGGLE SQUIGGLE SQUIGGLE ; Δ begin Σ ; Σ ; SQUIGGLE SQUIGGLE SQUIGGLE ; Δ ; Δ ; SQUIGGLE SQUIGGLE SQUIGGLE ; Σ ; Σ end]

I am referring to the squiggle that appears repeated three times after some semicolons and commas in the above clipping. It somewhat resembles a tilde `~`, but it is clearly a distinct symbol, since a normal tilde appears next to the delta.

Was this mark an ad-hoc invention or is it an established symbol? Does it have a recognisable name? What is its Unicode code point, if one exists?

(I don’t think there is a separate site for typography questions, but I did see that questions about typographical marks seem to be accepted here.)

Comment: You might do better over on one of the programming or computer science stacks, since it appears to be a symbol that is part of a specific programming notation (it appears to represent items of a subscripted list).

Comment: **﹏ ﹏ ﹏**  *Wavy low line* (U+FE4F). [[Graphemica](https://graphemica.com/%EF%B9%8F)]

Comment: I have vague recollections that this ~~~ represents a list but regret I have no memory of the name for the symbol.

Comment: The symbol does not appear in [List of mathematical symbols by subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols_by_subject) or in [Glossary of mathematical symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_mathematical_symbols). I suggest it is a **placeholder** for more `P` terms: *"`P, P, ﹏ ﹏ ﹏, P` is the ordered list of actual parameters ..."* So a glorified ellipsis.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about obscure mathematical symbology, not "use of English"

Comment: The programming communities might be more useful for this.

Comment: Whatever, I’ve already got an answer.

Comment: it is an obscure mathematical symbology that is in English. the use of English is required to use it in this context.